# check what checkboxes are checked and then send an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

**background on the topic**

ok ive been coding a messaging page which users come on to check their messages,this is done without moving from the page so it uses ajax and json calles to get the data through **jquery**

my question is

**If their a way of checking what checkboxes are **checked*** and then return there "ids" oh and their could be upto a 100 checkboxes if the user is lazy and doesn't clean his inbox*

if you want to look at what i mean go to http://125.239.244.47/social/
and login with the user **test** and the password is nothing(not the word)
and goto messages on the front page when you login
thanks for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Could you try it from javascript?I think it easily done through java script or jquery by looping and add ids of checkbox in array which are checked.

Comment: thats a good idea i might just try that i didn't even think about even through ive been doing loops all day(php) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, jQuery has a [Checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
var checkedBoxIds = $("input:checked").id();
```

Comment: Come on now, Rob. tq has already linked to this information in an epic Question.

Comment: yer i might try your code and this guys idea Shoaib Muhammad Khan well i think hes saying

Comment: Im going to mark this guy as he answered it but he didn't alone helped me i would like to say this guy helped me also Shoaib Muhammad Khan